# Can Flutter communicate with Java code only on Android?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

From what I understand, Java code that interacts with Flutter has to be put in the `android` directory. Does that mean using Java kills my app's cross-platform availability?

I should note, I'm not really coding in Java. I just have to use a piece of software that was written in Java, and is too big for me to rewrite in Dart.

Comment: Yes you'd only want to write Android-specific code in Java where possible. Anything done in Java would also have to be done in Swift if you want it to work the same way on iOS.

Comment: You're right that Java can only execute on android, but this doesn't necessarily stop your app from being cross platform compatible. You would simply need to provide platform specific code for any platform you do want to support - This is typically done through a plugin package: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I'm not really coding in Java. I just have to use a piece of software that was written in Java, and is too big for me to rewrite in Dart. I'll add  that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter allows us to call platform-specific APIs available in Java or Kotlin code on Android and in Objective C or Swift code on iOS.

Flutter’s platform-specific API works with message passing.

From the Flutter app, we have to send messages to a host on iOS or Android parts of the app over a platform channel. The host listens on the platform channel and receives the message. It then uses any platform-specific APIs using the native programming language and sends back a response to the Flutter portion of the app.

[this is a clear architectural view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBnyi.png)

Messages are passed between the Flutter Code(UI) and host (platform) using platform channels. Messages and responses are passed asynchronously and the user interface remains responsive.

On the Dart side using MethodChannel(API) we send a message which is corresponding to a method call. On the Android side MethodChannel Android (API) and on the iOS side FlutterMessageChannel (API) is used for receiving method calls and sending back results. These classes allow us to develop a platform plugin with very simple code.

If required, method calls can also be sent in the reverse direction, with the Android/IOS platform acting as the client and the method implemented in Dart.